# Conditional expectation inequality with squares

Tags: conditional-expectation

I am stuck on a question about conditional expectation, I was wondering if someone could give me a hint so I can make a start.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with finite mean and let $\mathbb{E}[X^2]<+ \infty$. Proof that $\mathbb{E}[X^2|Y]\geq (\mathbb{E}[X|Y])^2$ almost surely.

I have tried to write out something with the conditional variance, but this quickly showed that it did not work out. I don't really know how to continue.
Any hints would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Search the net for Jensen's Formula for conditional expectations.

Comment: $E\left [ \left ( X - E\left [X \mid Y  \right ] \right )^2 \mid Y \right ] = E\left [ X^2 \mid Y \right ] - E\left [ X \mid Y \right ]^2$